# SQL*Loader error ORA-00604 and ORA-02248

Tags: oracle, import, sql-loader

I've a Problem with Oracle's `SQL*Loader`.

```
SQL*Loader: Release 11.2.0.3.0 - Production on Tue Feb 11 14:32:00 2014
Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.
SQL*Loader-128: unable to begin a session
ORA-00604: Fehler auf rekursiver SQL-Ebene 1
ORA-02248: Ungültige Option für ALTER SESSION
```

This **Errormessage** occurs in the *Errorlog* after execute `sqlldr` with the following control and data file:

**sqlldr statement:**

```
sqlldr userid=%PW%/%Name%@%DBname% control=ABGRENZUNG_control.dat log=loader.log
```

**ABGRENZUG control file**

```
load data 
INFILE 'ABGRENZUNG.dat' 
INTO TABLE ABGRENZUNG
APPEND 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(AVG_RESTSCHULD,DATUM,DISAGIO,GEBUEHR,NOMZINS,REF_KEY,RESTSCHULD,STEUER_TYP,TYP,ZINSBETRAG,ZINSTAGE)
```

**ABGRENZUNG.dat:**

```
,20040630,0,0,,7514,3091209.0914799999,"S","T",11147.31048,
,20040731,0,0,,7514,3105526.7633799999,"S","T",17645.6519,
,20040831,0,0,,7514,3119926.1653200001,"S","T",17727.38194,
,20040930,0,0,,7514,3134407.7638500002,"S","T",17809.57853,
,20041031,0,0,,7514,3148972.0281699998,"S","T",17892.24432,
,20041130,0,0,,7514,3163619.43016,"S","T",17975.38199,
,20041231,0,0,,7514,3178350.44441,"S","T",18058.99425,
,20050131,0,0,,7514,3193165.5482000001,"S","T",18143.08379,
,20050228,0,0,,7514,3208065.2215300002,"S","T",18227.65334,
,20050331,0,0,,7514,3223049.9471700001,"S","T",18312.70564,
,20050430,0,0,,7514,3238120.21062,"S","T",18398.24345,
,20050531,0,0,,7514,3253276.5001599998,"S","T",18484.26954,
,20050630,0,0,,7514,3268519.3068400002,"S","T",18570.78669,
,20050731,0,0,,7514,3283849.1245499998,"S","T",18657.79771,
,20050831,0,0,,7514,3299266.44997,"S","T",18745.30542,
,20050930,0,0,,7514,3314771.7826299998,"S","T",18833.31265,
,20051031,0,0,,7514,3330365.6248900001,"S","T",18921.82226,
,20051130,0,0,,7514,3346048.4819899998,"S","T",19010.83711,
,20051231,0,0,,7514,3361820.8620799999,"S","T",19100.36008,
,20060131,0,0,,7514,3377683.27617,"S","T",19190.39409,
,20060228,0,0,,7514,3393636.2382,"S","T",19280.94203,
,20060331,0,0,,7514,3409680.2650600001,"S","T",19372.00686,
,20060430,0,0,,7514,3425815.8765699998,"S","T",19463.59151,
,20060531,0,0,,7514,3442043.5955400001,"S","T",19555.69896,
,20060630,0,0,,7514,3458363.9477300001,"S","T",19648.33219,
```

before executing the sqlldr statement I set these options.

> set nls_lang=AMERICAN_AMERICA.WE8MSWIN1252
>
> set nls_date_format='YYYYMMDD'

Comment: Ok, seems that the Problem occurs because of the nls parameters.
There must be a conflict with the nls_session_parameters.

I don't delete the question, because it may will help someone else.

But now i've a new Question. Will post it soon..

Comment: You can post your work as an answer and accept it as well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem occurs because of the NLS parameters. There must be a conflict with the `nls_session(or database)_parameters`.